# difficulty with form action and unique ids

Tags: php, html

I have this code in a foreach that lists  uniquecode links:

```
<a id="<?php echo $id_to ?>" href="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
  <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>      
<form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">                                
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

this is what I get when I view the page source:

```
<a href="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=36" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" > 
  KUZELJA<span class="pink_text">000</span>RC
</a>      
<form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=36">                                
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> 
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input> 
</form> 
<a href="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=38" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" > 
  ALANZIM<span class="pink_text">000</span>RC
</a>      
<form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/messageSent.php?id=38">                                
  <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> 
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input> 
</form>
```

the problem is when the action fires and page goes to messageSent and I view page source again `$id_to` is NOT the id of the link I clicked on. It takes the first link's id regardless of which link I click on?

here the messageSent page source (I clicked on link with id 38 *NOT* 36):
where I have a `print_r($_REQUEST)` and it gives:

```
Array
(
   [id] => 36
   [message] => bj,nbgj,
   [Submit] => Send
)
```

.

```
function showMessageArea(link)
{
  var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area');
  message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
  link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
  message_area.style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the `showMessageArea(...)` does, but I have a suspicion, that forms with non-unique ids (!!!) may be causing the wrong form to be shown and so you are in fact submitting another form than desired

Comment: function showMessageArea(link)
    {
      var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area');
      message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
      link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
      message_area.style.display="block";
    }
   
PLEASE HOW MUST I DO THIS? I AM DESPERATE :)

Comment: I don't work with PHP, so forgive me if am wrong here. But did you not hardcode 36 in that array ID I see above? Have you thought of dynamically setting the value of ID in that array rather than hardcoding? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed the non-unique ids.

Try appending `$to_id` to the form ids, so that they are unique (e.g. `<form id="message_area_<?php echo $to_id; ?>" ...`).

And then update `showMessageArea` function to do this:

```
var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+this.id);
```

This way you will be operating on the desired form element.

As a refactoring suggestion, I would suggest using a single form instead and make `id` parameter to be `<input type='hidden' name='id' id='message_id' value=''>` and set it's value from the `showMessageArea(...)` like this:

```
document.getElementById('message_id').value = this.id;
```

Comment: i have it like this now but it now it does not show my actual message area and submit button?
    function showMessageArea(link)
    {
      var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area_'+this.id);
      message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
      link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
      message_area.style.display="block";
    }

   <form id="message_area_<?php echo $id_to; ?>" 
or must i do the refactoring you suggested as well??

Comment: showMessageArea(link) is JS i must just add and what it does is diplaying my textarea and submit button directly underneath the link i clicked on...

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you have semi-colons after the php statements?

EDIT:

I think the problem is that there are two elements with the id "message_area", so it always refers to the first one. Try only having one form, and setting the action of that form when one of the links is clicked.

Comment: Ow the joys of these simple mistakes... The reason I never used any code my teachers gave me... They always forgot a semi-colon or similar things... That always lead to an hour of debugging instead of being finished in 30minutes

Comment: i added in ; everywhere! but still same outcome id is 36 in messageSent and not 38 which is the id of the link i clicked on

please can some-one just help?

Comment: A single statement within php tags like the echo above will run just fine without the semi-colon

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will fix it because I can't see an issue but could you try the following code:

```
<a id="<?php echo $id_to ?>" href="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
  <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>
<form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_to ?>" />
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And then try `print_r($_POST)`

**EDIT:**

Okay, following your comment Helloise, I believe the following may work:

```
<a id="messageid_<?php echo $id_to ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this,'<?php echo $id_to ?>'); return false;" >
    <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>      
<form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php">                                
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="message_id" name="id" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMessageArea(link,messageId)
    {
        document.getElementById('message_id').value=messageId;
        message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
        link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
        document.getElementById('message_area').style.display="block";
    }
</script>
```

So, here the main point is to have one form as you have stated but to pass the id we are using into the javascript function. From there, you can set the value of the hidden input which will then be included in the POST values.

Comment: not working...as mkilmanas said it is because my form id is not unique but how to get it unique?? OR have ONE form tag..if i have ONE form tag where do i place it in my code? i tried different places but then my page does not show the <a> 

i just dont know anymore..been struggeling with this for AGES!

Comment: @Helloise Smit Please see my update. By changing the way the javascript works, you can have one form that works for all links

Comment: thank you very much i will also try your code :) but i finally got it to work and get messagearea unique thus displaying the messagearea

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

after quick peruse...

- your missing `$` before `ADDRESS`. It should be `$ADDRESS`. I assume thats a variable (ignore this, overlooked its just a constant)
- your missing semi-colon after many lines of php.

  ```
  <a  id="<?php echo $id_to; ?>" 
      href="<?php echo $ADDRESS;?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to; ?>" 
      class="charcoal_link"
      style="line-height: 20px;"
      onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;"
      <?php echo $uniqueCode1;?>
      <span class="pink_text">
          <?php echo $uniqueCode2?>
      </span>
      <?php echo $uniqueCode3;?>
  ></a>      

  <form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo $ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to; ?>">                          
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
  </form>
  ```

Comment: ADDRESS can be a define and is probably not a variable. Semi-colons are not required in this case.

Comment: Right you are, overlooked its just a constant